# Java Database Connection practices

Tags: java, sql-server, connection

Should Connection (JDBS for SQL server) be closed strait away even if I intend on using it a moment later?

If I have a few methods in a Java class that both use Connection object, I create one connection, assign it as a property of the class, open and use the connection in first method (keep it open, do not .close() it)...don't use it for a moment (e.g. 10 seconds) then use the same open Connection again in a different method.  Is this considered bad practice?  i.e Should I close aftereach use?  Seems very slow in doing so?

Comment: Search for JDBC connection pool.

Comment: Connection pooling for 3 small operations?

Comment: Does not matter. You can always adjust number of connections to be used in the pool.